# List theme for pidgin?

Tags: themes, pidgin

I would like to give pidgin a try, but I don't like the default theme for the list, there is too much space between the contacts, I would like to style it in a more minimal way so i can see more contacts in less space. Despite my (not so thorough searches) I didn't find any theme specically for my list, I found for the icons and the sounds ... any proposals?

Comment: When I used Pidgin, i couldnt change the font size or spacing or other things for the list of buddies, and there was no theme that could do that.  Just thought I'd make a note of that.

Comment: @EvilPhoenix its been a while since I used it last time, and I remember losing few hair and hours while I was trying to set a font of my preference, but there is further implementation done in xml format for the themes so I hoped that something exists, if not I will contribute to the converter for adium themes which is not supporting list theming yet.

Comment: Mind letting me know which version of Ubuntu you're using?  I've got like 18 images in vbox, i can test stuff on there and see if i can get a full answer for you.  :/

Comment: @EvliPhoenix Maverick 10.10, till the new one arrives :)

Comment: For the time being I manage to use this list as a screenlet which is quite neat IMO, after all I am not really looking much from the guis http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/ePidgin+Theme?content=122236

Comment: Also if you select from the menu Buddies -> Show Details it becomes quite compact, consider the practical part of question answered, but the artistic part is still open :)

Comment: This is a REALLY old link, but this might help you (considering I cant find anything else short of finding new themes on the internet)  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=646254

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple alternative option, which lets you fit in twice as many entires, is to hide the buddy details of all the entires. Go to Buddies -> Show and then untick "Buddy Details."

Answer (score 4):

There are several plugins which can be used to improve the buddies list, which includes but not limits to:

### [Autoresize](http://raoulito.info/plugins/pidgin_autoresize/)

[image]

### Buddy list options: included in the [Plugin pack](http://plugins.guifications.org/trac/wiki/PluginPack)

[image]

### [Extended buddy list sort plugin](http://freakazoid.teamblind.de/2008/12/13/pidgin-extended-buddy-list-sort-plugin/)

[image]

And you can find more plugins in the [Pidgin's official plugin site](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins).

My buddy list have changed since it was originally installed and now it looks like this:

[image]

Well, probably not fully improved but better than the original.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't pidgin built on GTK+ ?

if so, you can use GTK themes to change things like font face & size and the interface elements. Something like the Clearlooks Compact theme will make the interface a little smaller so give you more room for the actual information. http://art.gnome.org/themes

Though as already mentioned, best is to use the specific buddy list plugins and disable buddy info to make a more dense list.